# Groovy - bind properties from one object to another

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to bind properties from one instance of a class to the properties of an instance of another class (the common fields between the two).  See the example below:

```
class One {
  String foo
  String bar
}

class Two {
  String foo
  String bar
  String baz
}

def one = new One(foo:'one-foo', bar:'one-bar')
def two = new Two()

two.properties = one.properties

assert "one-foo" == two.foo
assert "one-bar" == two.bar
assert !two.baz
```

The result is an error: Cannot set readonly property: properties for class: Two

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that for every object, `.properties` includes two built-in *Groovy-defined* properties, these are the `metaClass` and `class`. What you want to do is only set the *user-defined* properties. You can easily do this using code such as that shown below:

```
class One {
  String foo
  String bar
}

class Two {
  String foo
  String bar
  String baz
}

def one = new One(foo:'one-foo', bar:'one-bar')

// You'll probably want to define a helper method that does the following 3 lines for any Groovy object
def propsMap = one.properties
propsMap.remove('metaClass')
propsMap.remove('class')

def two = new Two(propsMap)

assert "one-foo" == two.foo
assert "one-bar" == two.bar
assert !two.baz
```

Comment: I am curious about the general approach. I have a web app connecting to a datawarehouse. The domain of the web app is quite different from the tables and data coming from the warehouse. I intend to use the above technic probably in the service layer but would you recommend to have an additional layer responsible to transform legacy objects to your domain objects?

Comment: This doesnt work the other way around since baz property is not defined on One

Answer (score 9):

I would choose **InvokerHelper.setProperties** as I suggesed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072307/copy-groovy-class-properties/23583744#23583744).

```
use(InvokerHelper) {
    two.setProperties(one.properties)
}
```

Comment: Does this handles `metaClass` and `class` properties safely? I mean, NOT overwriting them?

Comment: @Nikem This approach will not override metaClass or class. `import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

class A {
  String foo
  String bar
}

class B {
  String foo
}

A a = new A(foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar')​​​​​​
​B b = new B()

use(InvokerHelper) {     
  b.setProperties(a.properties) 
}

println b.properties​ // [foo:foo, class:class B]
`