# Groovy: Setting property values easily

Tags: groovy, javabeans, parameters

I have a map with name/value pairs:

```
def myMap = [
  "username"  : "myname",
  "age" : 30,
  "zipcode" : 10010
]
```

I have a class called User defined:

```
class User {
  def username;
  def age;
  def zipcode;
}
```

I would like to invoke the appropriate setters on the bean.  Is there a nice groovy way of doing this?  Note, I might have extra stuff in the myMap that wouldn't be set.  (The map is a form parameter values map)

I was thinking about using invokeMethod but I was assuming there was a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this: [Groovy - bind properties from one object to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370808/groovy-bind-properties-from-one-object-to-another)

And I realized I could do the following:

```
def prunedMap = [:]
myMap.each{
    if (User.metaClass.properties.find{p-> p.name == it.key}) {
        prunedMap.put(it.key, it.value)
    }
}

User user = new User(prunedMap)
```

Comment: You could also do: `new User( myMap.findAll { k, v -> k in User.metaClass.properties*.name } )`