# Groovy recursively copying properties plus applying calls per property

Tags: properties, groovy, clone

Using Groovy 2.0 (beta)....

Got a bean that has both simple (i.e. primitive) and complex (i.e. other beans as children) properties.  Want to recursively copy properties from a bean instance into a new bean and apply function calls per property.  For example, a property might contain an expression (i.e. something representing a value that hasn't been evaluated) and during the "clone"/"copy" phase I want to apply an evaluation so the new bean gets a concrete value.

New to Groovy and my stomach tells there is a simple way to handle this.  Beans are written in Groovy.

For example:

```
Source.name: '${xpath:applicationServer/name}'
Source.type: 'Server'
Source.create.name: 'com.bea:Name=${domain.name},Type=Domain'
....
```

the **name**, **type** fields are simple part of the Source class while **create** is complex (nested property).  When copying I want to evaluate the variables (i.e. ${xpath:...}, ${domain.name} based on a context, commons configuration setup).  Note the copying is done between objects of the same class.

Seen stuff like: [Copy Groovy class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072307/copy-groovy-class-properties) where an intersection between different classes is done but the construction of nested properties isn't recursive.

Comment: What do you mean by Groovy 2.0 beta? Also, do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Edited my original post with an example

Comment: @Tim, using Groovy 2.0.0-beta-SNAPSHOT inside Eclipse