# BeanUtils Converter custom class with nested objects

Tags: java, converters, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I need to copy the properties from one bean to another with same properties names.
I found the class BeanUtils and method copyProperties().
The problem is that in my beans there are nested objects.
So I tried to create a custom converter (implementing Converter interface) but I don't know how to map objects inside other objects and I don't know what I have to put inside the implementation of method convert().
I haven't found any solution for this problem.

Can you help me?

Regards.

Comment: copyProperties will make a shallow copy. I guess you want a deep copy. I suggest you do a search on deep copy in stack overflow. One discussion of deep copies is http://stackoverflow.com/a/15591144/4387162

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ 
Dozer is a Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data from one object to another. Typically, these Java Beans will be of different complex types.