# BeanUtils.copyProperties cuts String value

Tags: java, spring, apache, javabeans

I use a BeanUtils.copyProperties to copy one bean from another.
It doesn't matter if I use Apache or Spring's copyProperties.
They both cut my String and even transfer that cut value somewhere(only a gut feeling)

I have something like this,

```
    OriginalBean originalBean = session.getOriginalBean;
    OriginalBean cloneBean = new OriginalBean();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(originalBean, cloneBean);//source vs target depending on which import I use
```

originalBean would have something like this,

```
 String account;   //"550011"
 String accountNumber; //""
```

cloneBean would have something like this, after copyProperties,

```
String account;   //"0011"
String accountNumber;   //"55"
```

It is always the first 2 character.

Other string doesn't get affected by this. (or so I think for now)

The debugger would have above result, originalBean would be different from cloneBean for those String variables.

-------------1-2 weeks later------------------

Can't believe I missed this,
Bean has this but nothing uses it, nor is it the getter/setter. Wonder why it gets triggered.

```
public void setFullAccountForDisplay(String _value) {
    if (!Utilities.isEmpty(_value)) {
        account = _value.substring(0, 2);
        accountNumber = _value.substring(2, _value.length());
    }
}
```

Also found that our bean has a clone() method, will be testing this.

Comment: Please provide a complete and reproducible example.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, yeah I should have, and I will when I get a chance to recreate said issue(on a simpler scale). I guess I was hoping to find someone that had the same weird issue before.

Comment: why dont you use OriginalBean cloneBean=originalBean.clone()

Comment: @Jishnu Prathap multiple sites noting that .clone() method is flawed.
e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542504/should-we-use-clone-or-beanutils-copyproperties-and-why

Comment: Josh Bloch says cloning is bad when you compare it with a copy constructor. He's not defending `BeanUtils.copyProperties`, which seems to be broken in your case. I believe you could go with the copy constructor strategy. But regardless, do you have regular getters and setters for these two properties?

Comment: @JaredT just check whether you are getting same results?

Comment: @Thiago Porciúncula You have a good point, I'll be honest, I really didn't read the whole article. I was trying not to recreate the wheel if you know what I mean. 
Yes they do have getters and setters, do they have an affect? Nothing magical at best, just normal this.account = parameterAccount.

Comment: @Jishnu Prathap I will try it when I get back to the office tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm also thinking about using a deep clone, but it might be overkill and might hog resource.

Comment: @JaredT Yeah, it obviously makes more sense to use something that already exists and supposedly works. I'd really like to see a complete and reproducible example so we could investigate furthuer. But then again, it won't be a crime to go with the copy constructor strategy, and it will definitely by a better solution in terms of performance (which is probably not important in your case, but still).

Comment: My problem has been resolved. I used an existing cloning method we have :))...
Still wondering why a method inside the bean would have been triggered on CopyProperties though... :?