# Grails: how to programatically bind command object data to domain object in service?

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-orm

I have a command object that I want to convert into a domain object.

However, the object I want to convert the command object into may be one of two domain classes (they're both derived classes), and I need to do it in a service (which is where, based on other data, I decide which type of object it should be bound to).  Is this possible and what's the best way to do this?  `bindData()` only exists in a controller.

Do I just have to manually map command object parameters to the appropriate domain object properties?  Or is there a faster/better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the parameters have the same name, then you can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072307/copy-groovy-class-properties) to copy the values over. A quick summary can be as follows.

**Using the Grails API**

You can cycle through the properties in a class by accessing the `properties` field in the class.

```
object.properties.each { property -> 
    // Do something
}
```

You can then check to see if the property is present in the other object.

```
if(otherObject.hasProperty(property) && !(key in ['class', 'metaClass']))
```

Then you can copy it from one object to the other.

**Using Commons**

Spring has a really good utility class called `BeanUtils` that provides a generic copy method that means you can do a simlple oneliner.

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(object, otherObject);
```

That will copy values over where the name is the same. You can check out the docs [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html).

**Otherwise..**

If there is no mapping between them, then you're kind of stuck because the engine has no idea how to compare them, so you'll need to do it manually.