# Copy object properties to another object in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I was using a funky way to do it suggested in:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072974/4470135
So my code is:

```
def copyProperties(source, target) {
    def (sProps, tProps) = [source, target]*.properties*.keySet()
    def commonProps = sProps.intersect(tProps) - ['class', 'metaClass']
    commonProps.each { target[it] = source[it] }
}
```

What I get when I try to call a method that should convert an Entity into a Dto is:

> No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.keySet() is applicable
>   for argument types: () values: []\nPossible solutions: toSet(),
>   toSet(), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object),
>   get(int), get(int)

**UPDATE:**

My source is a Serializable bean with fields:

```
private String passengerName;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 5, max = 40)
private String destination;
@NotNull
private String departureDate;
```

My target is a JPA Entity with the same fields, but with an additional @Id field and a slightly different date representation:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
ZonedDateTime departureDate
```

Comment: Could you paste your Entity and Dto classes? Also showing a sample of copying one to another would be helpful.

Comment: It might be something to do with the way you are calling `copyProperties`. I mashed your version with the original thread and it worked fine.

Comment: I'd go with the first version on that post anyway.  `properties` also returns the values (e.g. expensive getters).

Comment: The first version works, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working, however, there are corner cases where it may break.

To fix this replace the property access `properties` with the method call `getProperties()`, which might be enough for your case. To cover all cases, you will need to write code for special cases (see bottom)

**Working example for the original version**

```
def copyProperties(source, target) {
    def (sProps, tProps) = [source, target]*.properties*.keySet()
    def commonProps = sProps.intersect(tProps) - ['class', 'metaClass']
    commonProps.each { target[it] = source[it] }
}

def a = new Expando()
a.foo = "foo"
a.bar = "bar"

def b = new Expando()
b.baz = "baz"
b.bar = "old"

copyProperties(a, b)

println b
```

**Example causing problems**

If the parameters have a property called `properties` I get the same exception you got (if the value is a `List`):

```
def c = new Expando()
c.properties = []
c.bar = "bar"

def d = new Expando()
d.baz = "baz"
d.bar = "old"

copyProperties(c, d)

println d
```

What works in both cases:

```
def copyProperties(source, target) {
    def (sProps, tProps) = [source, target]*.getProperties()*.keySet()
    def commonProps = sProps.intersect(tProps) - ['class', 'metaClass']
    commonProps.each { target[it] = source[it] }
}
```

Not that here I used an explicit call to `getProperties` rather than just accessing the `properties` property.

**We can still break this**

```
def e = new Object() {
    // causes same Exception again
    def getProperties() {
        return []
    }

    def bar = "bar"
}

def f = new Expando()
f.baz = "baz"
f.bar = "old"

copyProperties(e, f)
```

You can fix the last example for `e` by using the metaClass explicitly

```
def copyProperties(source, target) {
    def (sProps, tProps) = [source, target]*.getMetaClass()*.properties*.name
    def commonProps = sProps.intersect(tProps) - ['class', 'metaClass']
    commonProps.each { target[it] = source[it] }
}
```

However, that will fail due to `f`.

**Handle special cases**

```
def getProperties(Expando obj) {
    return obj.getProperties().keySet()
}

def getProperties(Object obj) {
    return obj.getMetaClass()*.properties*.name
}

def copyProperties(source, target) {
    def (sProps, tProps) = [source, target].collect {getProperties(it)}
    def commonProps = sProps.intersect(tProps) - ['class', 'metaClass']
    commonProps.each { target[it] = source[it] }
}
```

Here we give objects that need a special treatment what they need ;)
Note that this only works like this for groovy with `@CompileDynamic` as the decision which `getProperties` implementation is called will be made at runtime. The alternative is a check with `instanceof` for all the cases.

Comment: What a detailed answer! Thanks, @Mene!

Comment: Was fun, hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
User user = User.findById('1')
User copyUser = new User()
InvokerHelper.setProperties(copyUser, user.properties)
```